# How Do I Disable Alt-Drag Selection on an NSTextView?

Tags: cocoa, nstextview

I do not know, and cannot find, the standard technical term for the drag-select functionality when the alt/option button is pressed over an NSTextView.

When alt is pressed, the crosshair appears and text can be selected/highlighted in columns/vertically, as in Xcode.

I would like to disable this functionality in my NSTextViews, how can I do that please?

Comment: Is it that you want to limit the selection to single lines or that you really don't want the crosshairs to appear at all? Trying to figure out what is the best implementation for your needs :)

Comment: I think that the column selection only makes sense with fixed-width fonts, which I am not using. cmd-drag select for multiple part selections are fine. Definitely no cross hairs!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Digging into the disassembly of AppKit quickly reveals a hook which tells `NSTextView` whether the ALT+drag interaction should be enabled. It's the private method called `_allowsMultipleTextSelectionByMouse`. Altering its behavior does the trick but it is achievable only via private API. In this case, it should be pretty safe to do so.

There are following two ways for altering the aforementioned method:

#### Approach 1: `NSUserDefaults`

The method internally accesses the `NSProhibitMultipleTextSelectionByMouse` of `NSUserDefaults`. You can control the boolean value for this key on the app level. The downsides of this approach are:

- It can possibly be reenabled by the users of your app (e.g. via the `defaults` command line tool).
- It affects all instances of `NSTextView` in your app even those you don't necessarily want to alter.

#### Approach 2: Swizzling

The approach I decided to go with is a simple swizzle of this method in my subclass of `NSTextView`.

```swift
internal final class MyTextView: NSTextView {

    internal static func initializeClass() {
        try? MyTextView.swizzle(
            Selector(("_allowsMultipleTextSelectionByMouse")),
            with: #selector(getter: swizzled_allowsMultipleTextSelectionByMouse)
        )
    }

    @objc dynamic internal var swizzled_allowsMultipleTextSelectionByMouse: Bool {
        return false
    }

}
```

And somewhere in the app bootstrapping code like the `main` function you have to trigger the class initialization code by `MyTextView.initializeClass()`.

The code snippet above uses my own wrapper around the swizzling API but there are surely some libraries out there to use or you can follow the advices from [this article by PSPDFKit](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2019/swizzling-in-swift/).

Comment: Great answer! Thank you.